# how can i send request parameter into url?

Tags: java, jstl, jsp-tags

I am using following code but getting error .

```
<c:set var="temp1" value="${variableVal}" />
            <c:url var="urlVar" value="Testing.jsp">
        <c:param name = "DisParam" value ="${temp1}"/>
        </c:url>        
        <TD ><a class="Tabs" href="<c:url value="${urlVar}"/>">Testing</a>|</TD>
```

**but I am getting following error**

> Error Message: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not
>   found: /${urlVar} Error Code: 404 Target Servlet:
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor Error
>   Stack:  java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found:
>   /${urlVar}

I am using websphere version 8.0
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

So things are looking good here:

```
<c:set var="temp1" value="${variableVal}" />
<c:url var="urlVar" value="Testing.jsp">
    <c:param name = "DisParam" value ="${temp1}"/>
</c:url>
```

but instead of using the "urlVar" var that you created, you are using c:url to re-encode the contents of "urlVar".   You don't want to do that.   So replace:

```
<a class="Tabs" href="<c:url value="${urlVar}"/>">Testing</a>
```

with

```
<a class="Tabs" href="${urlVar}">Testing</a>
```

because urlVar should already be a nicely encoded URL with a parameter called "DisParam".

Note:  You could get rid of the first line:

```
<c:url var="urlVar" value="Testing.jsp">
    <c:param name="DisParam" value="${variableVal}"/>
</c:url>        
<TD><a class="Tabs" href="${urlVar}">Testing</a>|</TD>
```

Comment: Applied the solution. but still facing the same issue.